# $A$ and $B$ are different subsets of set $X$, $|X| = n$, $A \cup B = X$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

$A$ and $B$ are two different subsets of set $X$, $|X| = n$, such that

$$A \cup B = X$$

Solution of this equation is pair $(A, B)$. From all possible solutions we randomly choose one. What is probability that $A$ and $B$ contain exactly $k$ elements, $k > n / 2$?

I am new at probability theory but in this case the biggest difficulty is understanding what is number of cases that we are looking for and what is number of cases in general.

For me it seems like we don't have to consider case when $k < n/2$ at all because in this case it can't be solution to the equation. And after that we should use binomial coefficients. For example, let's firstly try to find number of all solutions of the equation $S$.

$$S = \sum_{i=n/2}^{i=n-1}\bigr({n \choose i}{n \choose i} - {n \choose i}\bigl)$$

I think so because we can choose elements in each subset exactly in ${n \choose i}$ ways, and after that we shouldn't forget that by condition these subsets should be different. But it's easy to see that this is wrong because I don't consider situation when we have different number of elements in subsets. It would be correct If I was calculating number of satisfying solutions but in this case it is not correct.

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: This might help: The solutions to $X=A\cup B$ are in bijection with filtrations $\varnothing \subseteq X_1\subseteq X_2\subseteq X$ by letting $A= X_2$, $B=X\setminus X_1$ or with partitions $X=Y_1\sqcup Y_2\sqcup Y_3$ by letting $A=Y_1\cup Y_2$, $B=Y_2\cup Y_3$. Maybe the filtrations or partitions are easier to count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|A|$ can range from $0$ through $n$. For any given $A$, $B$ must include $X\setminus A$, so $B$ is completely determined by $B\cap A$. Suppose that $|A|=k$. Then $A$ has $2^k$ subsets, any one of which can be $B\cap A$, so there are $2^k$ different sets $B$ such that $A\cup B=X$. $X$ has $\binom{n}k$ subsets of size $k$, so there are altogether $\binom{n}k2^k$ pairs $\langle A,B\rangle$ such that $A\cup B=X$. Summing over $k$, and remembering to subtract one for the pair $\langle X,X\rangle$, since $A$ and $B$ are required to be distinct sets, we find that there are

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k2^k-1$$

pairs $\langle A,B\rangle$ such that $A\cup B=X$ and $A\ne B$. The binomial theorem tells us that

$$(2+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k2^k1^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k2^k\,,$$

so

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k2^k-1=3^n-1\,.$$

We have to include all of these pairs, including the ones in which one of $|A|\le\frac{n}2$ or $|B|\le\frac{n}2$, because they are all in the pool of solution from which we’re randomly selecting one. This number will be the denominator of the probability that we seek.

I did it this way to demonstrate that the general approach that you had in mind can be made to work. However, there’s an easier way to get this denominator. If $A\cup B=X$, then $X$ is the union of the three pairwise disjoint sets $A\setminus B$, $A\cap B$, and $B\setminus A$. Conversely, if $X$ is the disjoint union of sets $C,D$, and $E$, we can set $A=C\cup D$ and $B=D\cup E$ to get a pair $\langle A,B\rangle$ such that $A\cup B=X$. Thus, we get one such pair for every we of splitting $X$ into three parts. We can imagine running through the $n$ elements of $X$ one at a time, putting each of them into one of the three sets $A\setminus B$, $A\cap B$, and $B\setminus A$, and then combining the first two sets to get $A$ and the last two to get $B$. There are $3^n$ ways to make this sequence of choices of which element goes in which set, and we have to throw out the one that puts every element of $X$ in $A\cap B$, since the pair $\langle X,X\rangle$ isn’t allowd, so we end up with $3^n-1$ possible pairs $\langle A,B\rangle$ such that $A\cup B=X$ and $A\ne B$.

The numerator will be the number of pairs $\langle A,B\rangle$ such that $A\ne B$, $A\cup B=X$, and $|A|=|B|>\frac{n}2$. Suppose that $\langle A,B\rangle$ is such a pair, and $|A|=|B|=k$. Then $|A\cap B|=2k-n$, and $A\cap B$ can be any subset of $A$ of this size, so there are $\binom{k}{2k-n}$ possible choices for $A\cap B$ and hence for $B$. There are $\binom{n}k$ choices for $A$, so there are altogether $\binom{n}k\binom{k}{2k-n}$ pairs $\langle A,B\rangle$ such that $|A|=|B|=k$ and $A\cup B=X$. We can’t have $k=n$, as then we end up with the pair $\langle X,X\rangle$, so to get the total number of ‘successful’ pairs we need to sum over integers $k$ greater than $\frac{n}2$ and less than $n$:

$$\sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^{n-1}\binom{n}k\binom{k}{2k-n}\,.$$

(Here I’ve used the fact that $\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1$ is the smallest integer larger than $\frac{n}2$.) For example, for $n=5$ we get

$$\sum_{k=3}^4\binom5k\binom{k}{2k-5}=10\cdot3+5\cdot4=50\,,$$

and for $n=6$ we get

$$\sum_{k=4}^5\binom6k\binom{k}{2k-6}=15\cdot6+6\cdot5=120\,.$$

The denominators in these two cases are $3^5-1=242$ and $3^6-1=728$, respectively, so the probabilities in question are $\frac{50}{242}=\frac{25}{121}\approx0.2066$ and $\frac{120}{728}=\frac{15}{91}\approx0.1648$.

I do not immediately see any nice closed form for this summation; for what it’s worth, the general term can also be written $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!^2(2k-n)!}$.

Comment: Thanks! I never tried to consider $X$ as union of $A\setminus B$, $B\setminus A$ and $A \cap B$, very interesting approach!

Comment: @math-traveler I did suggest doing that $2$ hours ago :-P

Comment: @Christoph: You did indeed, but in sufficiently compressed form that I suspect that it wasn’t understood.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This wasn't directed at you! Your answer is perfectly fine and I wasn't saying my comment would have done the job. I was just pointing this out to OP, who hasn't considered partitions even though I pointed in exactly that direction :)